# Как перейти в директорию ниже по уровню?

Tags: python

Например, у меня есть программа по пути: /C:\Users\User\Desktop\123\bin\python\scripts. В ней есть модуль, который вычисляет, в какой директории находится программа. Мне нужно вернуться на папку обратно: /C:\Users\User\Desktop\123\bin\python и там уже открыть папку images. Какой модуль нужно использовать, чтобы спуститься в директорию ниже по уровню?

Comment: нужно всего лишь составить новый путь, а не использовать какой-то модуль. Программы не ходят по папкам так, как вы это возможно  себе представляете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перемещение по папкам, то есть смена текущей рабочей директории, осуществляется при помощи модуль `os`

```
os.getcwd() #возвращает текущюу рабочую директорию, по умолчанию та же где запущенный скрипт
#c:/a/b/c/d/e/f 
os.chdir('../')  #подняться на уровень вверх, ../../../ подняться на три уровня вверх ../f2 подняться на уровень вверх и перейти в папку ф2
#c:/a/b/c/d/e
os.chdir('./') # текущая директория
#c:/a/b/c/d/e
os.chdir('f2') #перейти в папку находящуюся в текущей папке
#c:/a/b/c/d/e/f2
os.chdir('c:/a1/b1') # перейти по абсолютному пути
#c:/a1/b1

#os.chdir('../images') #для вашего случая
```